# Paste a link option doesn't work

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

I'm trying to update my career profile, I want to add one of my own answers via the option of pasting the link, but I can't. 
I tried several answers, but I still get the below error.

[image: Error message]

Can anyone assist me on that ? The alternative choice is to pick one of the top answers but it is not what I want.